# Showing that an action of a group on a set is proper

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $X$ represent the set = $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$

Then the elements of the symmetry group (Dihedral Group- $D_8$) permute the elements of the set.

**How do I show that the action of $D_8$ on the set is proper?**

I understand that the group G must be a topological group (which is continuous) and so it must therefore be infinite.

What I am stuck on is that the group is not infinite.

I have used this website but I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: What is the topology on $X$?

Comment: That would be the Dihedral Group - D8

Comment: Thanks for the reply btw :)

Comment: A topological group need not be infinite. Every finite group is a topological group when equipped with the discrete topology.

Comment: Oh right thank you. Can I just say that since it is a topological group then it will act on the topological set of X?

Comment: You have said "the action of $D_8$ on the set" but you haven't said which action. Also, the notation $D_8$ is unfortunately ambiguous. It is a dihedral group of order either $8$ or $16$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It should be of order 8. Sorry if I conveyed it unclear, it should be the group action of a topological group on a topological space.

Comment: Your edit has made the question completely meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that you would include:

G×X->X×X(g,x)|->(gx,x) and relate it to the answer, although I cannot be certain.

Sorry :P

Comment: is someone able to tell me if this is correct please.